# How to check #API calls against rate limit for IBM Watson Conversation service

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

How can I find out how many API calls were already made against the rate limit for the IBM Watson Conversation sevice?

Comment: Do you mean how many times you have called, the rate limit, or something else?

Comment: Exactly, for monitoring the rate limit

Answer (score 0):

This worked for another service under watson. Check whether same can be used for conversation too.

http://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/info/GetAPIKeyInfo?apikey="your-api-key"

Should get response as xml.

sample response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
<status>OK</status>
<consumedDailyTransactions>500</consumedDailyTransactions>
<dailyTransactionLimit>1000</dailyTransactionLimit>
</results>
```